# UIGestureRecognizer Clashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

[image: Details Hierarchy]

This is a basic look at my UI hierarchy.

`GroupPageVC` -> `[GroupVC]`

`GroupVC` -> `MediaPageVC` and `CardVC`

`MediaPageVC` -> `[MediaVC]`

`MediaVC` -> `ProfileView` and `CommentView`

`[]` means array.

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` in the `MediaPageVC`'s view, another in the `ProfileView`, and one more in the `CommentView`.

The problem is that the tap recogniser in the `MediaPageVC`'s view is consuming the gestures, and they aren't getting down to the `ProfileView` or `CommentView`.

How can I cleanly resolve this, without trying to communicate all the way up and down the stack myself?

Comment: Try to set to false cancelsTouchesInView flag in gesture recognizer.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but unfortunately it didn't work.